# How to fetch records from a table where values are same for minimum three rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have created following table:

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 |

```
Create Table Test3
(
    id int,
    val int
)

Insert Into Test3 Values (1,0),(2,1),(3,0),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,0)
```

I want output as

| id |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

because consecutive three values are same in [val] column. And if the 7th row also has 1 the that id number should also reflect in output.

How can I solve this?

I have tried this with self join but not getting the expected output.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.

Comment: What if you have more than three values consecutively? I am guessing here that the id column is how you are ordering the data?

Comment: @SeanLange Got it man. Sorry for this. I hardly use this so I couldn't know much about this

Comment: wherever I will have consecutive values that I want in O/P

Comment: What does "wherever I will have consecutive values that I want in O/P" mean?

Comment: The desired output is not clear. Are you looking to return three rows, one for 4, one for 5, and one for 6? If so, so you need the `val` column also? Or, are you expecting one row with comma-separated items? Also, what would you want to see if the `(7,0)` row was instead `(7,1)`, and you have more than three consecutive items?

Comment: @AshishKarnavat, you can create the table with values in [DBFiddle] (https://dbfiddle.uk/) for easier sharing and debugging of the issue.

Comment: @MohitGoyal The ddl statements are enough. From there it's less than 10 seconds to paste into a fiddle yourself.

Comment: Finally, I believe the most likely answer to my question about the output will indicate this is a **gaps and islands** problem. For some reason I have a mental block around this and have to look up how to do gaps and islands every time myself... and if I have to do that, now that you know what to search for you can also do it just as quickly on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `LAG` and `LEAD`:

```
SELECT id, val
  FROM (
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (Val = LAG(Val,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AND Val = LAG(Val,2) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) 
                 OR (Val = LEAD(Val,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AND Val = LEAD(Val,2) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) 
                 OR (Val = LEAD(Val,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AND Val = LAG(Val,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Cnte
  FROM Test3
       ) a
 WHERE Cnte >= 1;
```

| ID | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |

If you extend the example data:

```
VALUES (1,0),(2,1),(3,0),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,0),(8,3),(9,3),(10,3),(11,10),(12,4),(13,4),(15,4),(16,4)
```

| ID | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 12 | 4 |
| 13 | 4 |
| 15 | 4 |
| 16 | 4 |

Comment: Don't you want AND not OR?  It is for 3 consecutive and not 2

Comment: The test data does not have two items consecutive to test -- but if it did your code would have a bug.

Comment: This has been accounted for. Likely best to edit comments rather than post them sequentially.

Comment: @PatrikHurst what if I want 4 consecutive same values in output?

Comment: A minimum of four? You'd need to edit the conditions to match that.
If you want more then 3 (including 4 etc) this is already functional.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
DECLARE @TEST
  TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    VAL INT
)
;
   
INSERT
  INTO @TEST
VALUES (1,0),(2,1),(3,0),(4,1),
       (5,1),(6,1),(7,0),(8,1),(9,1)
;

SELECT
       ID, VAL
  FROM
       (
        SELECT
                ID
               ,VAL
               ,LEAD(VAL) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS LEAD_VAL
               ,LAG(VAL) OVER (ORDER BY ID)  AS LAG_VAL
          FROM
                @TEST
       ) X
 WHERE
         X.VAL = X.LEAD_VAL
      OR X.VAL = X.LAG_VAL 
;
```

Here is the result with my data set:

| ID | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |

I had concerns about the end conditions causing problems because of the NULLS, so I added a consecutive set at the end. It seems to not be bothered by the nulls.

You can look up LEAD and LAG in Microsoft's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

We can build islands of consecutive rows that have value 1, then filter them by minimum length.

```
select id
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by rn1 - rn2) as cnt
    from (
        select t.*,
            row_number() over(order by id) rn1,
            row_number() over(partition by val order by id) rn2
        from test3 t
    ) t
) t
where val = 1 and cnt >= 3
order by id
```

This uses the difference between row numbers to define the islands - a typical gaps-and-island approach; you can run each level of subquery independently to see how this works.

| id |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DZby8vNq)